# Nsfilemanager error

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager

the `availableDate` part is not working properly I think??

```
NSFileManager *filey = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:savedTextMsg];

    NSString *tMessage=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[filey availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

No visible `@interface` for `NSFileManager` declares the selector `availableData` is the error message..
What does that mean exactly?
Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-fileHandleForReadingAtPath:` returns an `NSFileHandler`, so you need to change the first line to

```
NSFileHandler *filey = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:savedTextMsg];
```

The error message occures because you declared `filey` to be an instance of `NSFileManager`, and that class does not declare a method `-availableData`.

Comment: Ah yes... I can see that now... :-) Thanks